# Complex nested classes in java

Tags: java

I am Testing Program with a number of nested static classes.

```
public class Q 
{
    static class A {

        static class B{

            static class C{

                static class D{

                    static class E{

                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }


    class C{

        class D{

            class F{

            }
        }

        static class E{
    }
}

}
```

But here i cant declare static class E second time .Which shows error "static modifier not allowed here". Whats wrong with me?
Don't shout me. I know its a bad practice .But I have the curiosity to know the reason.

Comment: It is so annoying to read such a code.

Comment: Why on earth would you try anything as scary like that?

Comment: This is so scary @user3007882. Looks like a ladder. What do you want to achieve using this?

Comment: Any specific reason for using this code??

Comment: Don't shout me. I know its a bad practice .But I have the curiosity to know the reason.

Comment: It is not annoying me: it is a tipical Oracle Exam Certification question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why a non-static inner-class cannot have static members (fields and methods)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684844/why-a-non-static-inner-class-cannot-have-static-members-fields-and-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify all that code down to just:

```
class C{

    static class E{
    }
}
```

So the question becomes why can a static inner class not be created within a non-static inner class.

This is answered here:

[Why a non-static inner-class cannot have static members (fields and methods)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684844/why-a-non-static-inner-class-cannot-have-static-members-fields-and-methods)

> The entire body of a Non-static inner class is Not within a static scope, and therefore you can't have static members in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class C{

        class D{

            class F{

            }
        }

        static class E{
    }
}
```

If you take a close look at the nested inner classes above, you are trying to put static nested class within a non-static inner class, which is not permitted in java.