# Is there a reason why these rules are implemented in java anonymous class

Tags: java

As far as I know the differences between regular class and anonymous class are:

- Anonymous class can't implement multiple interfaces whereas regular class can.
- Anonymous class can't extend class and implement interface at the same time
  whereas regular class can.
- Anonymous class doesn't have a name while regular class has.
- Anonymous class can't define a constructor because anonymous class doesn't have a name whereas regular class can.

Is there a reason why these rules are implemented in anonymous class?

- static fields of anonymous class must be constant.
- an interface can't be a member of anonymous class.
- static block/initializer can't be used in anonymous class.

Comment: 'Anonymous class doesn't have a name' is a tautology, and there is no syntax to support the remainder of your first four points.

Answer (score 1):

Because JLS [15.9.5. Anonymous Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) says:

> An anonymous class is always an **inner class** ([§8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)); it is never static ([§8.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1), [§8.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1)).

And JLS [8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) says:

> It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a static initializer ([§8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)).
>
> It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly `static`, unless the member is a constant variable ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).

Note that interfaces are implicitly `static`.

See also question:

- [Why a non-static inner-class cannot have static members (fields and methods)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11684844/5221149)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I don't read JLS documentation that much because it's too technical and the documentation itself is too intimidating.